# TrueQ - Test of inequality

Tags: equation-solving

I want to look if a term is `<0`,`>0` or `==0`. What is wrong when I write

```
a < 2 b;
b > 0;
a > 0;
TrueQ[Re[(3 a + 6 b + 
    Sqrt[9 (-36 + 7 a^2) + 4 a (-27 + 8 a^2)*b + 
      4 (-45 + 16 a^2) b^2 + 32 ab^3])/4 (a + b)] < 0]
```

It gives me  `FALSE` every time regardless of whether I say `<0`,`>0` or `==0`. But I took the real part, hence it one case has to be `TRUE`!

For a=2b

```
Simplify[Re[(-3 a - 6 b + 
   Sqrt[9 (-36 + 7 a^2) + 4 a (-27 + 8 a^2)*b + 
     4 (-45 + 16 a^2) b^2 + 32 a b^3])/4 (a + b)] < 0, 
Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, a = 2 b}]
```

I get

```
Re[Sqrt[-9 - 4 b^2 + 16 b^4]] < True
```

What does this means?

**EDIT****EDIT**

For

```
Simplify[Re[(-3 a - 6 b + 
   Sqrt[9 (-36 + 7 a^2) + 4 a (-27 + 8 a^2)*b + 
     4 (-45 + 16 a^2) b^2 + 32 a b^3])/4 (a + b)] < 0, 
Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, a == 2 b}]
```

I get

Re[Sqrt[-9 - 4 b^2 + 16 b^4]] < 2 b

Does this means that this is only true if Re[Sqrt[-9 - 4 b^2 + 16 b^4]] < 2 b

?

Comment: `TrueQ` returns `False` for anything that is not explicitly `True`. Since you have a symbolic expression the truth can not be determined explicitly.

Comment: What do you think the first three inequalities do here? They do *not* put any constraints upon `a` and `b` in what follows!

Comment: But when a and b >0 and with a=2b you can decide if its larger than 0 or not? Is there a possibility in mathematica to do that?

Comment: the point is your first three lines do not do what you think. In fact they do nothing.. Think about it.

Comment: You seem to think that the line `a<2b` is an assertion, in which you declare a certain truth, but it is not. It is a Boolean test. You may need $Assumptions and a function using them like Simplify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
a<0
```

you are not affecting a in any way. i.e. you are not saying to Mathematica 'a is less than zero'.  I think that what you intend to do is

```
Simplify[Re[(3 a + 6 b + 
       Sqrt[9 (-36 + 7 a^2) + 4 a (-27 + 8 a^2)*b + 
         4 (-45 + 16 a^2) b^2 + 32 a b^3])/4 (a + b)] < 0, 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, a < 2 b}]
```

This will simplify your expression and, in this case, it returns False.  So, your expression is not less than 0 given the constraints.

Comment: Ok that works! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

May be try `Assuming` as follows:

```
Assuming[{b > 0, a > 0 && a < 2 b}, 
 Refine[Re[(3 a + 6 b + Sqrt[9 (-36 + 7 a^2) + 4 a (-27 + 8 a^2)*b + 
          4 (-45 + 16 a^2) b^2 + 32 a b^3])/4 (a + b)] > 0]]
```

Which gives:

> True

Whereas

```
Assuming[{b > 0, a > 0 && a < 2 b}, 
 Refine[Re[(3 a + 6 b + Sqrt[9 (-36 + 7 a^2) + 4 a (-27 + 8 a^2)*b + 
          4 (-45 + 16 a^2) b^2 + 32 a b^3])/4 (a + b)] < 0]]
```

gives

> False

**Edit**

And for the case `a == 2b`

```
 Assuming[{b > 0, a > 0 && a == 2 b}, 
     Refine[Re[(3 a + 6 b + Sqrt[9 (-36 + 7 a^2) + 4 a (-27 + 8 a^2)*b + 
              4 (-45 + 16 a^2) b^2 + 32 a b^3])/4 (a + b)] < 0]]
```

We get:

> False

Comment: I edit my first post. For the case a=2b I get an expression I cant interpret!

Comment: @user2098925. Did you use double equal sign `==`? So `a == 2 b` instead of `a = 2 b`. See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

You can define global assumptions

```
$Assumptions = {b > 0, a > 0, a < 2 b};

Re[(3 a + 6 b + 
   Sqrt[9 (-36 + 7 a^2) + 4 a (-27 + 8 a^2)*b + 
     4 (-45 + 16 a^2) b^2 + 32 a b^3])/4 (a + b)] > 0 // Simplify
```

> True

Comment: True + Re[Sqrt[-9 - 4 b^2 + 16 b^4]] > 0....This I get for a=2b. what does this means?

Comment: I get this for a=2b. what does this means?

Comment: I edited my first post, the same like the previous comment

Comment: @user2098925 It means that result depends on value of `b`, e.g. `b==0` and `b==1`.